# Parsing a string in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, parsing

I have a 32 bit string that I want to parse into 8 bits each. Then I want to change the 8 bit binary into a single integer, for example:

`str = '00000001000000100000001100000100'`

`output = '1 2 3 4'`

I know to use `bin2dec`, but I'm having difficulty parsing the string.

Comment: `str(1:8)` is the first 8 digits, `str(9:16)` is the next octet, etc.  MATLAB strings are just matrices of character type, so all your usual matrix arithmetic, indexing, searching, can be used.

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab every string is a matrix, so you can use this property. If 8 bits belong to one byte, reshape your data to have one byte per row:

```
reshape(str,8,[]).'
```

Doing so, you can apply `bin2dec` to get the output:

```
output=bin2dec(reshape(str,8,[]).')
```

This returns a vetor `[1;2;3;4]`, use `num2str(output.')` if you want a char array instead.

Comment: Nice.  I didn't consider reshaping the array.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as how Ben Voigt didn't provide an answer to this question even though he pretty much answered the question in the comments, I will provide one for closure.  As he said, you can segment your string into 8 characters each.  Strings are essentially an array of characters.  As such, split up your string into 8 characters each, then apply `bin2dec` on each of the strings.

```
str = '00000001000000100000001100000100';
byte1 = bin2dec(str(1:8));
byte2 = bin2dec(str(9:16));
byte3 = bin2dec(str(17:24));
byte4 = bin2dec(str(25:32));
output = num2str([byte1 byte2 byte3 byte4]);

>> output

output =

1  2  3  4
```

Looking at your example output, you desire `output` to be a string, and thus the `num2str` call in the last line of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
>> 2.^(7:-1:0)*reshape(str-'0',8,[])
>> ans =
        1     2     3     4
```

Of course, apply `num2str` if you need the output in the form of a string.

---

A more esoteric way:

```
>> fliplr(typecast(uint32(2.^(31:-1:0)*(str-'0').'),'uint8'))
>> ans =
        1    2    3    4
```